# Change display language option missing in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, language, language-pack

I am missing the "Change display language" link in my Control Panel as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: 1]

I can't reach language properties in any way, like Start Menu search, changing the view of control panel etc. What is wrong with it?

Comment: 1) If you have the **Local Group Policy Editor** (Start / Run / gpedit.msc), under `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Control Panel\Regional and Language Options`, are any of the options such as *Restricts the UI language Windows users for all logged users* enabled? 2) Try running `sfc /scannow` from an elevated command prompt. 3) Run `Windows\System32\intl.cpl` and see if you can change the display language from the [**Keyboards and Languages** tab](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6hjzg.jpg).

Comment: @Karan Isn't that a full-fledged answer?

Comment: @BenjiWiebe: I guess... Not sure if any of the suggestions will definitely solve the OP's issue though, so thought perhaps I'll wait till he responds with results. Also, Devid seems to have hit upon an important point which might explain why the option's missing.

Comment: 1.None of the options were enabled and they have been set to "Not Configured".2)After running this command it gave me this response: "verification 30% complete.  Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation"3)It asks me  to Install display language language! I think i Would not have problem with this option,The problem is running of this window and a link that has vanished!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have Windows 7 Ultimate ? If not that is the problem, cause only in Windows 7 Ultimate or Enterprise you can change from Control Panel the display language. In other Windows 7 versions you will need to hack the registry.

---

If you are running Windows 7 Ultimate but can't see the options under Control Panel try first to install MUI (Multilingual User Interface).

1. Start -> All Programs --> Windows Update --> Optional Updates.
2. Open optional Updates and go to the section Windows 7 Language Packs.
3. Tick the Multilingual User Interface (MUI) you want and click OK
4. Proceed with Install Updates

[image: Windows Optional Updates]
**Note** If the optional update links cannot be found, click Check online for updates from Microsoft Update to search the optional updates.
[image: Windows Search Online for Updates]

To change **the display language**, follow these steps:

1. Click Start, and then type Change display language in the Start
   Search box.
2. Click Change display language.
3. In the drop-down list that appears, select the language that you
   want, and then click OK.
4. Log off for the changes to take effect

Comment: +1 Good catch, perhaps this is the answer. Ultimate and Enterprise have this feature. For other versions, [this](http://mark.ossdl.de/2009/08/change-mui-language-pack-in-windows-7-home-and-professional/) might help.

Comment: I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate Service Pack 1. Could it solve the problem?

Comment: @user201329
Then try to do the following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwdmukiE7xM

Comment: @user201329 if you upgrade to Windows 7 Ultimate you should be able to change the display language from the control panel.

Comment: @Devid But i'm not!

Comment: @user201329 Can you tell us exactly what Operating System you have ?
Because above you say that you are running Ultimate Service Pack 1

Comment: Yes. I'm Running Windows 7 Ultimate And i am not able to change the display language from the control panel

Comment: @user201329 look the above post, i updated it. Try to see if you can now change the display language.

Comment: I can run "region and language" windows Through a "c:\Windows\System32\intl.cpl" and  I can change the language package from this Window.I am Wondering Why the link of this window has been vanished from control panel  as i shown in screenshot!

Comment: @user201329 Ok we thought that you can't change your language. The next time to get better answers you should specify exactly what you want. The question should be more like: **Why did the display language setting disappear from Control Panel?**. I don't have a clue why you can't see the option from control panel. But maybe you should take the Windows 7 Installation disk and run it on your computer and click on repair errors or search for errors. This might fix the problem.